# I need jQuery advice

Tags: jquery

I am  writing my first project in PHP and I have a problem connected with jQuery.

In my test.html page I have a `<div>` and in there are 3 buttons, one above the other.
When the user clicks the top button, I want a new `<div>` created under that button with a textbox and one new button (x button). The other 2 buttons must be moved.
After clicking x button, everything should return to its initial state.

On the [jQuery homepage](http://jquery.com/) if you click the “run code” button you will see what I want.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Doesn't the 'run code' example you referenced basically give you the answer? It's using a .show() method to show a hidden P.

Comment: You need spelling advice mate. Ha ha! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code from the front page:

`$("p.neat").addClass("ohmy").show("slow");`

What this is doing is referencing the p tag that has a class of "neat", adding a class of "ohmy" (which is likely styled in CSS), and causing the event "show" to happen slowly.

The p tags existed already, and were hidden (likely using a CSS attribute of display:none) and then shown using JQuery.

JQuery has great documentation.  I would suggest that you go through some of the tutorials and get a feel for how it works.

[JQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)